# Are "PAN" (Personal Area Network) and "ad-hoc network" two terms for the same thing?

Tags: networking, ad-hoc-network, terminology, pan

When searching the Internet for help solving various issues involving networking my devices via Bluetooth and/or Wi-Fi it seems that the terms "ad-hoc network" and "personal area network" (PAN) are sometimes used interchangeably.

Do they actually mean the same thing?

Or is one properly a subset of the other?

Or is PAN standardized and ad-hoc not?

Or is one term preferred by one or more companies, OSes, communities?

Comment: Arguably, Bluetooth classic is a PAN that is not ad-hoc, mostly using your phone as the hub. Whereas BLE is very ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1):

A Personal Area Network is typically an ad hoc network, but the terms are not interchangeable.

PAN is differentiated by range, typically up to a few meters, although I've seen definitions describing up to 10 meters.  It's intended to connect devices within a short distance of a user (hence the "personal").  One of those connected devices could link to an external network, to access the Internet, for example.
[Starting source for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_area_network)

An ad hoc network is one that is created as or when needed for a purpose by the devices, themselves, rather than connecting the devices via a network infrastructure, like a router.
[Starting source for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network)

Comment: Here is an example of a Wide Area Ad-hoc Network https://gizmodo.com/clusterduck-is-ibms-rubber-duck-inspired-wifi-system-fo-1834563832, nothing personal about this.